# How/Where can i find the members of the structure pthread_attr_t and pthread_condattr_t ?

Tags: linux, pthreads, ubuntu-14.04

To use the pthread_cond_init() api, i need to pass the second argument as the pointer to the structure type pthread_condattr_t. I tried looking into Man pages, pthread.h and some other header files, i didn't get the definition of the structures(pthread_condattr_t, pthread_attr_t). Where are they defined ?

Thanks and Regards,
R Madhu

Comment: You can probably just do a regexp search in the pthread headers, but note this from manpage: 'The pthread_attr_t type should be treated as opaque: any access to
       the object other than via pthreads functions is nonportable and
       produces undefined results.' Violating the spirit of an API is usually a bad idea.

Comment: thanks @ErikAlapää